# Parse Plain Text

Tags: java, parsing, plaintext

How Can I parse this string:

> PING 192.168.1.2 (192.168.1.2) 56(84) bytes of data.64 bytes from 192.168.1.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.244 ms64 bytes from 192.168.1.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.274 ms64 bytes from 192.168.1.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.275 ms64 bytes from 192.168.1.2: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.306 ms64 bytes from 192.168.1.2: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.550 ms--- 192.168.1.2 ping statistics ---5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4001msrtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.244/0.329/0.550/0.114 ms

I tried using `StringTokenizer` but not getting appropriate result.

Code I tried is follow:

```
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(pingResult, ":");
String first = tokens.nextToken();// this will contain "Fruit"
String second = tokens.nextToken();
```

Comment: What should be the parsed string result ??

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: @BrijeshThakur  Expected Result should be "icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.244 ms"

Answer (score 3):

Try a regex match:

```
public static void findMatch(){
        String str = "PING 192.168.1.2 (192.168.1.2) 56(84) bytes of data.64 bytes from 192.168.1.2" +
                ": icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.244 ms64 bytes from 192.168.1.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.274 ms64 " +
                "bytes from 192.168.1.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.275 ms64 bytes from 192.168.1.2: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.306 ms64 " +
                "bytes from 192.168.1.2: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.550 ms--- 192.168.1.2 ping statistics ---5 packets transmitted, " +
                "5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4001msrtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.244/0.329/0.550/0.114 ms";

        String regexPattern = "icmp_seq=\\d+ ttl=\\d+ time=.+?ms";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexPattern);

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

        while (matcher.find()){
            System.out.println(str.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()));
        }
    }
```

Result:

icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.244 ms

icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.274 ms

icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.275 ms

icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.306 ms

icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.550 ms

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
 while(tokens.hasMoreElements())
{
   String subStringValue = tokens.nextToken();
   System.out.println("token : " + StringUtils.substringBetween(subStringValue, "", "ms")+"ms");
}
```

[StringUtils.substringBetween](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#substringBetween%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 2):

Alone `StringTokenizer` won't work. `StringTokenizer` with `substring` can be used to achieve the expected result. i.e. `StringTokenizer` will give tokens as "`icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.244 ms64 bytes from 192.168.1.2`". You can do substring from the tokenized String. something like :

```
String finalString=tokenizedString.substring(0,tokenizedString.indexOf(ms)+1);
```

Though the answer is a bit dirty but it solves the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use String split method.

```
ArrayList<String> ResultTab= new ArrayList<String>();
    String pingResult = "PING 192.168.1.2 (192.168.1.2) 56(84) bytes of data.64 bytes from 192.168.1.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.244 ms64 bytes from 192.168.1.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.274 ms64 bytes from 192.168.1.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.275 ms64 bytes from 192.168.1.2: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.306 ms64 bytes from 192.168.1.2: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.550 ms--- 192.168.1.2 ping statistics ---5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4001msrtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.244/0.329/0.550/0.114 ms";
    String[] pingResultTab = pingResult.split(":");
    for (int i = 0; i < pingResultTab.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(pingResultTab[i]);
        if(i >= 1)
        {
            String[] itTab = pingResultTab[i].split("ms");
            ResultTab.add(itTab[0]);


        }

    }
    System.out.println("---RESULTAT-------");
    for (String result : ResultTab) {
        System.out.println(result);

    }
```

Comment: I guess the above solution will give you "icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.244 ms64 bytes from 192.168.1.2"  which is not expected.